# Two related list 'new' buttons behave differently

Tags: page-layout, master-detail, button, urlhacking

I have a page for a parent object with two related lists on it. Both related lists are master-detail relationships with the parent object. On both related lists, the standard 'new' button is enabled for creation of related objects. I have not overridden any of the standard buttons or actions in either of the child objects. All three objects are custom objects.

When I use the button to make a new child object type A, and save, I am redirected to the screen for the parent record. When I do the exact same thing for object B, I am shown the detail screen for the child record. I would like both buttons to behave the same in this respect.

At the parent record page, I examined the page source and noticed this difference between the two buttons:

```
<td class="pbButton"><input value="New Shop Task"  class="btn" name="new00N36000001ahHe" onclick="navigateToUrl('/a04/e?CF00N36000001ahHe=WO%23000487&amp;CF00N36000001ahHe_lkid=a02360000044auI&amp;saveURL=%2Fa02360000044auI&amp;retURL=%2Fa02360000044auI','RELATED_LIST','new00N36000001ahHe');" title="New Shop Task" type="button" /></td>

<td class="pbButton"><input value="New Material Request"  class="btn" name="new00N36000001b5m2" onclick="navigateToUrl('/a07/e?CF00N36000001b5m2=WO%23000487&amp;CF00N36000001b5m2_lkid=a02360000044auI&amp;retURL=%2Fa02360000044auI','RELATED_LIST','new00N36000001b5m2');" title="New Material Request" type="button" /></td>
```

The first button has a parameter for 'saveURL' and the second does not. I understand that I could override the 'new' button to change this for the second object type, but I'm having trouble understanding why the two buttons behave differently in the first place. What else could be causing this?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen anything like this before.
You really need to provide more screen shots of the setup, and of the result.

Your description is quite good, and because quite good there are not many questions to ask. to fault find this I think you need to work through the setup again.
Maybe it is a permissions thing, no access to object A???